# API AI Recognise Infinitely varying reference

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

#### My Issue

Im currently working with API.AI for an chat bot system. Im coming up against an issue where I need to be able to recognise a booking reference in a string of text.The problem that I am having is that this booking reference has no real pattern to it, they are generated at random. But are always 5 chars long, for example ABC12.

#### Current Attempt

I've given API.AI examples (as an entity) of how these can look, and have switched on Automated Expansion. In my intent I have then given examples of how a user may structure these for example 'My booking reference is ABC12' and denoted where the booking reference can be found.

How ever many examples I give it just doesn't seem to recognise this. Have I done something wrong / am I missing something?

Any help would be much appreciated.